# Change some look for html on basis of selection of text

Tags: javascript, iphone, html

In my app there is an html file showed in a webview. I have a note functionality where when user selects text, it is highlighted and an image is added as suffix. This note is then saved as an html file.

So for this functionality, I have written a java script function.

```
function highlightsText()
{

    var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var selectionContents = range.extractContents();

    var newDate = new Date;
    var randomnumber= newDate.getTime();

    var div; 

    var imageTag = document.createElement("img");
    imageTag.id=randomnumber;
    imageTag.setAttribute("src","notes.png");

    var linkTxt = document.createElement("a");
    linkTxt.id=randomnumber;
    linkTxt.setAttribute("href","highlight:"+randomnumber);

  linkTxt.appendChild(selectionContents)

    div = document.createElement("span");


div.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
div.id=randomnumber;

linkTxt.appendChild(imageTag);
div.appendChild(linkTxt);

range.insertNode(div);


    return document.body.innerHTML+"<noteseparator>"+randomnumber+"<noteseparator>"+range.toString();
}
```

Here I am making a span and this span holds my highlighted text with image.

Now `problem` is,

When I am selecting a paragraph, it only adds an image and does not highlight the text.
If I use div or p tag in place of span then it gives an entire line for a single word which looks rather odd.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: div tags will get a linebreak before and after (usually, most browsers do this, considering it is a "division"/block level element), you're better off using a span.

And secondly you should append the selection contents to the span

ispain.appendChild(selectionContents) !! and do not forget the semicolon ;)

on a side note, you do know that:
1- you can't have html element ids starting with digits.
2- having more than one elements with the same id is gonna get unpredictable when you're selecting em.

Comment: using span is not working when selecting text from two paragraphs.